# Flowtype: Interface can't be combined with union type

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

This example uses an interface and throws an error ([try this example](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAdgFwKYCdIEMBjTUAUQA91s8AxZTaAE1AG9FRRVYsAuUAZ0poA5gBpEAX0SJ0ATwAOxAMoBXAkT59QAXhb9V6vr0rLMI0ADc80E7wBGsWNEx5UocQG5p84tTzInTNqkFFS09EwAZLp8+pgavPjQfKagONiw2LwC2MJunl4KoABKcXKwqMlBKmpxmgA+oL7+mAz5kMqoBOjI5aAAFi4MTiV8ZRWYABTYpeXJvCNjyQCULGygyJCgUzPjAHQxNRorrOzsltgWVjag9o7OrjrTo7OYu5bWmO6gIKAA6hkAaz4AEI1uJUkliCdTudUth0pl+IJUEIgk9Fq80hkvj9-tggaD2JJJEA)):

```
// @flow

interface ExtraField {
  note: string;
}

type Success = ExtraField & { success: true, value: boolean };
type Failed  = { success: false, error: string };

type Response = Success | Failed;

function handleResponse(response: Response) {
  if (response.success) {
    var value: boolean = response.value;
  } else {
    var error: string = response.error; // Error!
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
Cannot get `response.error` because: Either property `error` is missing in `ExtraField` [1]. Or property `error` is missing in object type [2]
```

**Notes**:

1. When switching from an `interface` to a `type` the error is gone, i.e. when writing `ExtraField` as:

   ```
   type ExtraField = {
     note: string
   }
   ```
2. @AluanHaddad found two other weird things ([try the different cases here](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAdgFwKYCdIEMBjTUAUQA91s8AxZTaAE1AG9FRRVYsAuUAZ0poA5gBpEAX0SJ0ATwAOxAMoBXAkT59QAXhb9V6vr0rLMI0ADc80E7wBGsWNEx5UocQG5p84tTzInTNqkFFS09EwAZLp8+pgavPjQfKagONiw2LwC2MJunl4KoABKcXKwqMlBKmpxmgA+oL7+mAz5kMqoBOjI5aAAFi4MTiV8ZRWYAAwAFNil5cm8I2PJAJQsbKDIkKAzc+MAdDE1Gmus7OyW2BZWNqD2js6uOrOj85j7ltaY7uwgpEVFADyRQ24lSSWIZ3Ol1S2HSmX4glQQiCL2W7zSGU87EkkkQ7U63V6A1QQ0wSzeAEZdq9xos9qt1uwtjsAISstFvQ6xE5M6F4K6fW73JwuVEM95C77nP4kAHA0HgypQi4C2HwrJIlHPCX7THYbFuCRSP4AdQAggAVAD8oAAtKAABIIUAEWAAW2I6D6yE0vtADC2kBwmAwoG9YpJZIp40poGtCfxHS6PVcUeGEoATDT0fTaYyoSyc1yjgZtFodMZMKcNqrBTdMHYHKKnqBOQcpYawfRlbXrld9ZqcsjxfmMXCsaDjUA)):

   - When changing `if (response.success) {` to `if (!!response.success) {` the **error will remain**.
   - But when changing `if (response.success) {` to `if (response.success === true) {` the **error will go away**.

I don't quite understand why an `interface` won't work here. The error is weird. The field `error` doesn't appear in `ExtraField`.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Please read both questions. They are very different and not a duplicate.
I'm using a similar adapted example from the flow docs to make it easier for people to answer which perhaps make them appear to be similar. 

Please ask a question in a comment to know more if you are still unsure why they are different or help me with an answer.
And please reopen this question. I've put a lot of effort in creating it with a simple example for others to understand.

Comment: OK, reopened now

Comment: This is very confusing. Look at this code (which works) https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAdgFwKYCdIEMBjTUAUQA91s8AxZTaAE1AG9FRRVYsAuUAZ0poA5gBpEAX0SJ0ATwAOxAMoBXAkT59QAXhb9V6vr0rLMI0ADc80E7wBGsWNEx5UocQG5p84tTzInTNqkFFS09EwAZLp8+pgavPjQfKagONiw2LwC2MJunl4KoABKcXKwqMlBKmpxmgA+oL7+mAz5kMqoBOjI5aAAFi4MTiV8ZRWYABTYpeXJvCNjyQCULGygyJCgUzPjAHQxNRraWjrGmCus7OyW2BZWNqD2js6uOtOjs5i7ltaY7qAgUAAdQyAGs+ABCNbiVJJYiXK43VLYdKZfiCVBCILvRZfNIZf6AkHYcFQ9iSSRAA

Comment: And it gets weirder https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAdgFwKYCdIEMBjTUAUQA91s8AxZTaAE1AG9FRRVYsAuUAZ0poA5gBpEAX0SJ0ATwAOxAMoBXAkT59QAXhb9V6vr0rLMI0ADc80E7wBGsWNEx5UocQG5p84tTzInTNqkFFS09EwAZLp8+pgavPjQfKagONiw2LwC2MJunl4KoABKcXKwqMlBKmpxmgA+oL7+mAz5kMqoBOjI5aAAFi4MTiV8ZRWYAAwAFNil5cm8I2PJAJQsbKDIkKAzc+MAdDE1Gmus7OyW2BZWNqD2js6uOrOj85j7ltaYnuziqUnEM7nS6pbDpTL8QSoIRBF7Ld5pDI-NwSKTtTrdXoDVBDTBLN4ARl2r3Giz2q3W7C2OwAhDS4W9DrETpTgXgrp9bvcnC5YeT3pzvhs-vRKkCLuzQeCslCYc9+ftEdhkZJJCBQAB1ACCABUAPyIdFdHqubG4-HjABMxPhZJJFKB1JtjKOBm0Wh0xkwpw2Eo5N0wdgcPKeoAZB0FKv+Yt91yuSplOWhfPtCLBSOFEiAA

Comment: @AluanHaddad This is really crazy!! Thanks for the examples! I'll add these observations to the question!

Comment: Intersection types in Flow seem to be "badly broken" (https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6482#issuecomment-421167167). I think the example should be better if you use object type spread. [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAdgFwKYCdIEMBjTUAUQA91s8AxZTaAE1AG9FRRVYsAuUAZ0poA5gBpEAX0SJ0ATwAOxAMoBXAkT59QAXhb9V6vr0rLMI0ADc80E7wBGsWNEx5UocQG5p84tTzInTNq6AHSh5JQ0dIxmfPqYGrz40HymoDjYsNi8AtjCbp5eCqAASvFysKgpQSpq8ZoAPqC+-pgMBZDKqAToyBWgABYuDE6lfOWVmAAU2GUVKbyj4ykAlCxsoMiQoNOzE8GxtRqrrOzsltgWVjag9o7OrjozY3OYwZbWmJ7s4mnJxCenc5pbAZLL8QSoIRBJ5LV7pTJfNwSRBAA).

Comment: Agree with @user11307804 Just a tip: always use exact types + spread. Try not to use interfaces, not-exact types and intersaction types.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting. I didn't know you could spread fields of a type into another type definition. Looking for it in the docs I only found it mentioned in the section talking about React props. 
@user11307804 Do you want to create an answer mentioning in the spread operator?

Comment: Sure thing! Did it work for you? I don't often like answers that circumvent the problem, but in this case I think it's appropriate because intersections are broken (given that it does actually solve your problem).

Comment: @user11307804 I know what you mean, but it really solved my issue and I come back here to review your solution in the comment. It would be easier to have it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Intersection types in Flow seem to be "badly broken" ([see this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6482#issuecomment-421167167)). I think the example should be better if you use object type spread.

```
// @flow
interface ExtraField {
  note: string,
}

type Success = { success: true, value: boolean };
type Failed  = { ...ExtraField, success: false, error: string };

type Response = Success | Failed;

function handleResponse(response: Response) {
  if (response.success) {
    var value: boolean = response.value;
  } else {
    var error: string = response.error;
  }
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAdgFwKYCdIEMBjTUAUQA91s8AxZTaAE1AG9FRRVYsAuUAZ0poA5gBpEAX0SJ0ATwAOxAMoBXAkT59QAXhb9V6vr0rLMI0ADc80E7wBGsWNEx5UocQG5p84tTzInTNq6AHSh5JQ0dIxmfPqYGrz40HymoDjYsNi8AtjCbp5eCqAASvFysKgpQSpq8ZoAPqC+-pgMBZDKqAToyBWgABYuDE6lfOWVmAAU2GUVKbyj4ykAlCxsoMiQoNOzE8GxtRqrrOzsltgWVjag9o7OrjozY3OYwZbWmJ7s4mnJxCenc5pbAZLL8QSoIRBJ5LV7pTJfNwSRBAA)